# How to explain the topic of Fourier transform interactively?

Tags: undergraduate-education, concept-motivation

This is a soft question . In the walk-in for the lectureship, I have decided to give demo lecture on the topic of **Fourier transform**.

The principal of the institution ask me to take lecture  interactively with students on the given topic for **around 20 to 25 minutes**.  I should teach them interactively by which they can learn Fourier transform with interest.

But I could not dare to counter question him **"How to make and teach Fourier transform topic interactive one making use of given time span?"** ;-)

Now,I am confused with what should be the start of the lecture? Should I take any example or any application than directly coming on equations or any other ?

What  should I tell about importance of Fourier transform? The important factors of signals I.e. phase,frequency and amplitude ? So can anybody help me for it?

Comment: There are many questions posed here. Which one is the main question, and is it meaningfully different from your previous post, also about Fourier topics, which was closed as a duplicate? cf. [**MESE 8106**](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/8106).

Comment: @Benjamin sir ,1.I want  to give demo lecture in another institute for recruitment purpose 2.As it is said that my question is duplicate of another person's question, can anybody explain me how is it so?
3. I want to make use of the given 20-25 minute time slot in which I have to decide many things like how to start the lecture,equation explanation, examples whose answers are not at all given in any of the previous questions (also in the  question due to which my question is called as "duplicate") 4.in any of the previous questions ,no information is given about how to interact with students

Answer (score 1):

Go in with two or three ideas/themes/topics to discuss, and be prepared to abandon them to handle the classroom.  The demo (in my view) is about how you will handle less standard situations, and not so much about how to deliver a good standard lecture.  In general, there will be students who aren't interested whom you are expected (or at least hoped) to draw out and help them engage their brains.  There are some who will want to grab attention and direct it to a particular topic related to but away from the main topic: how will you help them and guide the discussion back to topic?  There are those rare few cases who will be disruptive; you will have to handle them and keep the rest of the class on track.

I imagine they will be pleased at new insights or refreshing ways to present Fourier transforms, but that would not be my priority as a member of committee who is evaluating a lecturer for hire.  If you have time and political savvy, it might help your case to send a letter to the appropriate person confirming your understanding of the time, location, and other details.  You can also slip in what you believe are the things they are looking for, and suggest that you are willing to change your presentation if there are different things they wish to see/evaluate.  (Don't send such a letter if it feels wrong or if something else suggests it is a bad idea.)

Gerhards "Always More Than One Goal" Paseman, 2015.06.07